# preg_replace and pattern expression problem with rich text file and PHP 7.4

Tags: php, regex

I am extracting the file-content from a rtf document.
I am clearing out the rtf coding using the following expression.

```
$strFileData = file_get_contents('testdata/test.rtf',true)
 $strCleanedFile = preg_replace('"{\*?\\\\.+(;})|\\s?\\\[A-Za-z0-9]+|\\s?{\\s?\\\[A-Za-z0-9‹]+\\s?|\\s?}\\s?"', '', $strFileData);
```

And this is an example of a line before exeucting my regex:

```
{\loch\cf17\fs13\dbch\af7\loch MARTHA SAYERS 003145840 909090KU1 OTH 04/09/22 3 COMM $1895.70 $189.57 $0.00 $0.00 $189.57 USD $189.57} \par \pard\plain \s21\rtlch\af9\afs24
```

And this is what it looks like after executing my regex:

```
MARTHA SAYERS 003145840 909090KU1 OTH 04/09/22 3 COMM $1895.70 $189.57 $0.00 $0.00 $189.57 USD $189.57
```

But I need to keep the following in the file for line breaks:

```
} \par
```

How can I adjust the pattern to do this ??
I have tried several modifications to no avail.

Added: this is what the actual detail looks like before executing my regex -

Comment: You'd probably need a proper parser for this.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The expression works very well and all rtf codes are gone. But in part of the data, I need to retain the paragraph breaks.

Comment: Your regular expression is complicated enough already. It's not pretty, but you could replace all the `\pard` and `\par` with some other, known, complex sequence (something that would not appear in the actual text, like `%%%pard%%%` and `%%%par%%%`, then do the `preg_replace`, then swap the placeholders back. But as @ceejayoz points out, there are a few rtf-parsing libraries out there; how certain are you that these are the only exceptions you will come across?

Comment: In fact, what if someone put one of those sequences you clean up into the text of the document (I didn't take the time to figure it out for sure, but if you rendered your question above using RTF, your cleaning expression would probably break it.)

Comment: This question does not yet contain a [mcve].

Comment: I did not post what a detail line actually looks like - I edited my original post to show an actual line. It is before I execute the regex to clean out the rtf coding.

Comment: So you are seeking `MARTHA SAYERS 003145840 909090KU1 OTH 04/09/22 3 COMM $1895.70 $189.57 $0.00 $0.00 $189.57 USD $189.57} \par` as the exact, desired result?  `\pard\plain \s21\rtlch\af9\afs24` is okay to be removed?  Does a realistic string contain more than one line of text?

Comment: Yes, the block of data will contain many lines like I posted. I can not post the actual data - (privacy). And yes, the:   <pre><code> \pard\plain \s21\rtlch\af9\afs24 }  </pre></code>  can be removed

Comment: Note- no matter how I tried, 4 spaces  and ctrl-k to denote coding - couldn't get it work in my response...sorry

Comment: Jerry - I think your right about using a substitute value. I have been playing with and I think it's the route I might go. I have used that approach before with good results.

Comment: I tried to mark Jerry's response as a solution but there was no button to click on to do so...